# How to authenticate and get data from soundcloud without callback popup?

Tags: javascript, meteor, soundcloud

When I use the API it always pops up the callback HTML page. Since I have the client id, is it possible to authenticate and get data from the server using the client id?

Comment: Soundcloud seems to use OAuth.  Having only a client id does not allow for a full authentication.  You need a callback html in order to actually *do* the authentication with SC.

Comment: Doest that mean the callback.html always have to pop up every query I send to the server. I would want it to not show any popups when I access public playlists, track from soundcloud but it is always asking for authentication.

Comment: SoundCloud have pretty [good documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs).  You should read through it and then if you have a specific problem ask a question here. :)

Comment: @DavinTryon thanks for the comment. I found the answer. I had to provide a non-expiring token on connection. 
https://gist.github.com/jbutko/fed567b860a30242e287